# Python: After FIND and Replace with re.sub , I get STX on that line

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have this line with 2 html tags:

`<p class="mb-40px"><!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->`

I use Python, and this regex to delete the first tag, so to remain only `<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->`

**THIS IS THE REGEX CODE:**

```
if len(re.findall('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', page_html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) != 0:
    page_html = re.sub('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', '\2', page_html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    counter_img += 1
```

Seems that replacement was made, but instead of second tag, I get this:

STX (I believe is ANSI or UTF-8 character). See the print screen:

[STX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ie0M.png)

Comment: try `re.sub('<p class="mb-40px">', '<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->', page_html)`

Comment: thanks, almost work your regex. I modify a little bit. I put it as an answer.

Comment: "ANSI" is not well-defined in this context. STX is an ASCII control character (also known as ctrl-B).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BackReference with Python Regular Expression with Unicode](/q/12106596/90527)

Answer (score 2):

The string `'\2'` is the ASCII character ctrl-B, also known as STX. To get a literal backslash in the substitution, use a raw string `r'\2'`, or double the backslash.

There is no need to run `findall` separately; `re.sub` will simply do nothing if there are no matches. If you want to find out whether any substitutions took place, maybe turn to `re.subn`:

```
page_html, count = re.subn('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', r'\2', page_html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if count:
    counter_img += 1
```

Tangentially, notice also that `!` is not a regex metacharacter, and thus does not need to be escaped with a backslash. (As you were not using a raw string for the regex, either, that backslash would also have had to be doubled in order for it to do anything. I believe that in future versions of Python, superfluous backslashes like this would even be an error.)

Answer (score 1):

Solution by: @Ramesh

`re.sub('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', '<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->', page_html)`

So the final Find and Replace should be:

```
if len(re.findall('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', page_html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) != 0:
    page_html = re.sub('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', '<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->', page_html)
    counter_img += 1
```

**Or, Second solution (if you want to use `r''` ):**

```
if regex.search('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', page_text, flags=regex.MULTILINE) != 0:
    page_html =  regex.sub('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', r'\2', page_html, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    counter_img += 1
```

Comment: just simply ignore this line in your code`if len(re.findall('(<p class="mb-40px">)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)', page_html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) != 0:`